# Correcting vertical alignment of navbar link in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into a weird issue with Bootstrap 4's `.navbar` class in my Rails application.

In short, I am making a navbar, and I am trying to add a link on the right side. According to [the documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/), the `.pull-**-right` class should work within the navbar and put the link on the right side.

Now it successfully does that; however, the vertical alignment is off (even though the `navbar-brand` link on the left is perfect):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light" style="background-color: #002b52">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <%= link_to "Example", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    <%= link_to "About Us", about_path, class: "pull-sm-right navlink" %>
  </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It didn't work originally, so I made up the `.navlink` class and added some CSS with:

```
.navlink {
      vertical-align: middle; 
 }
```

Even after doing so, the right link isn't centered vertically (it's close to the top) even though the `navbar-brand` is with no extra CSS magic.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing Bootstrap **v3** classes with **v4** while not using the default navigation structure found in the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#supported-content), particularly this: see [Nav](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav). And the class `navbar-header` doesn't exist in **v4**.

Hopefully this helps.

**Basic Setup**

```
.navbar
  a.navbar-brand
  ul.nav.navbar-nav
    li.navbar-item
      a.nav-link
```

**Rails Example:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light">

  <%= link_to "Example", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item pull-sm-right">
      <%= link_to "About Us", about_path, class: "nav-link" %>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #002b52;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav li > .nav-link,
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Example</a>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item pull-sm-right">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because .navbar-brand has a lot of extra classes on it. did you want your links different font sizes or all the same??

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

just remove the classes off the links and leave the class navbar-brand or refer to the docs https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

here is what you are after

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-6" data-toggle=
            "collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle
            navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class=
            "icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id=
        "bs-example-navbar-collapse-6">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

this was from the docs which i linked

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, but here's the challenge. `navbar-brand` is formatted correctly and rendered on the left side. For the other links, I want them to be aligned to the right side, hence why I used another class.